# Path Concatenation Using Remote OS Separator

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm trying to use `pysftp` with an external Linux server, but when I try to concatentate path and file names using `os.path.join()` or `pathlib.Path()` they understandably default to the local (Windows) path separator `\\`. `'/'.join()` does the trick, but doesn't feel like the right answer, but might be the best solution.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path, PosixPath

os.path.join('path', 'to', 'file.txt')
# path\to\file.txt -- Windows

Path('path') / 'to' / 'file.txt'
# path\to\file.txt -- Windows

'/'.join(('path', 'to', 'file.txt'))
# path/to/file.txt -- Posix
```

Often enough, I'm getting the `path/to` from the current working directory of `pysftp` so feeding that in rather than building the entire path string manually, the `'/'.join()` method is still the only one that works.

```
os.path.join('path/to', 'file.txt')
# path/to\file.txt -- Mixed

Path('path/to') / 'file.txt'
# path\to\file.txt -- Windows

'/'.join(('path/to', 'file.txt'))
# path/to/file.txt -- Posix
```

Is there a way to force `os.path.join()` or `pathlib.Path` to use the Posix separator while I'm running on Windows? I tried setting the `sep` attribute of `Path`, but it seems like that would have to be done for each Path individually even if it didn't raise the `AttributeError` and it doesn't seem to want to let me instantiate the `PosixPath` class directly.

```
p = Path('path/to')
p.sep = '/'
# AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'sep'

PosixPath('path') / 'to' / 'file.txt'
# NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'PosixPath' on your system
```

Trying to "trick" the `os` module with `os.name = 'posix'` or `os.sep = '/'` doesn't work either

```
print(os.name)
# nt
print(os.path.join("path", "to", "file.txt"))
# path\to\file.txt -- Windows as expected
os.sep = '/'
print(os.path.join("path", "to", "file.txt"))
# path\to\file.txt -- Windows as expected

os.name = 'posix'
print(os.name)
# posix
print(os.path.join("path", "to", "file.txt"))
# path\to\file.txt -- still Windows.
os.sep = '/'
print(os.path.join("path", "to", "file.txt"))
# path\to\file.txt -- still Windows.
```

Should it matter, I'm running python 3.7.0

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `os` imports either `ntpath` or `posixpath` depending on what it determines your operating system to be from `os.name`. Unfortunately we know renaming `os.name` or `os.sep` doesn't work without a module reload, but you can get away with importing the two path modules directly:

```py
>>> import posixpath
>>> import ntpath
>>> ntpath.join('asds','asdf', 'adf.txt')
'asds\\asdf\\adf.txt'
>>> posixpath.join('asdfa','asdf','asdf.txt')
'asdfa/asdf/asdf.txt'
```

or setting `os.path` if you want to use `os`

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py'>
>>> os.path = ntpath
>>> os.path
<module 'ntpath' from '/home/usr/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ntpath.py'>
>>> os.path.join('asdfa','asd', 'asdf.txt')
'asdfa\\asd\\asdf.txt'
>>> os.path = posixpath
>>> os.path.join('asdfa','asd', 'asdf.txt')
'asdfa/asd/asdf.txt'
```

An alternative to using `os` would be to use the forward slash `/` as your path separator in your code. This is cross-platform.

`'path/to/somefile.txt'`

Comment: if I was hard coding locations, then sure, but it's not very flexible. And since I'm using `pysftp` to find the files in the first place, I can't exactly hard code it anyway. As indicated in my answer `'/'.join()` works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make `os` or `pathlib` use a format other than the local system.

Comment: updated answer. I wasn't able to test it across both OS but this code runs in Ubuntu.

Comment: see here for more: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py

Comment: I also found this: https://effbot.org/librarybook/ntpath.htm

looks like you can `import posixpath` and `import ntpath` separately.

Comment: I've updated the question with the results i got from your suggestions. I will also note that i logged into an ubuntu server running python 3.5.2 and my results do not match what you show.

Comment: @Cohan, last try :)

Comment: now i feel dumb for not looking at `posixpath` after nixing `ntpath`. I even saw it in the standard library, just didn't go for it. Thanks for the tenacity.